# How to get image/video Extension/format Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I use Cordova.Camera API for get image,it will return imageuri.
but in android imageuri  is

image file : com.android.providers.media.documents/document/**image**%3A3717

video file : com.android.providers.media.documents/document/**video**%3A3718

it doesn't have file extension like .jpg .png.I use Cordova.file api to get the file then check file.type result is **undefind**.

in ios extension is attach with file name like : somewhere/file.jpg

How can I resolve my problm?   thankyou.

Comment: Not really a proper answer, but I use the Base64 encoded image. If I need to display it before uploading I use an `<img>` tag with the Base64 data as the source.